# How can I create multiple views in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, ddl

I want to create a temporary stored procedure to create several views; so something like this:

```
create proc #t1 as
begin
   create view v1 as select 1 as x
   go
   create view v2 as select 2 as x
end
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this in Microsoft SQL Server 2005, I get a syntax error on the first `create view` line.

Something like this works:

```
create proc #t1 as
begin
   exec('create view v1 as select 1 as x')
   exec('create view v2 as select 2 as x')
end
```

However, this seems like a terrible way of doing what I want.

So what's wrong with the first attempt, and what's the best way to create multiple views in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why would you want to create something like a view inside a stored proc?? A view is a part of your database - it should be created with your other DML statements....

Comment: "this seems like a terrible way of doing what I want" - I agree (for both forms). Maybe if you can tell us what you're trying to accomplish as an overall goal, we can suggest a solution. As marc_s says, you don't generally create views as part of a stored proc.

Comment: I can think of no circumstance where creating a view in a stored proc is good thing to do.

Comment: @HLGEM, @Damien, @marc: I need to create and initialize a database from a Java application. I have an SQL script that does the initialization, but I can't execute the script through JDBC unless I parse it out into individual statements; there are libraries that can do this. There are also command line tools that I can use to execute an arbitrary SQL script. I was exploring another option, which is to wrap the entire script into one temporary procedure. The script, of course, contains GO, hence this last approach would not work.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a `go` inside a stored procedure. It's not a command in SQL, it's a separator between batches in the SQL Manager, so it will cut the procedure into two batches and cause syntax errors because neither batch is a complete command.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write a full blown parser to make this work - all you need to do is what the command line tools/SSMS do - read lines from the file and accumulate them in a (in .Net, it's a stringbuilder, can't remember the equivalent in Java) until you encounter a line which starts with the word `GO`. Each time you reach that point, send your accumulated buffer to SQL Server, and then empty your buffer and start again.

So long as your current script has `GO` whenever it's required, the above should work.

Comment: How do you send, empty and then start again?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy you can achieve this using variable,assign the create view to the @variable  then EXEC(@Variable) statements inside the procedure